# How to check one line with all the lines from the base .txt, then if there are matches, then write this line in a separate text file?

Tags: python

There is a variable a1 = "cosmodrome", there is also a database (there are many words, each word on a separate line) - base.txt.

It is necessary to make the value of the variable a1 comparability with each row of the database. If there is at least one match, then write the value of the variable a1 to a separate text file a_new.txt.

The coincidence is even the presence of the necessary order of letters, that is, the cosmodrome = cosmodromes, this is considered a coincidence (true).
If there are no matches, then you need to write the value of the variable a1 to the variable a2.

I'm not very good at working with files and strings, please help, at least with ideas.

I tried like this, nothing turned out:

```
  f2 = open("base.txt",mode = 'r',encoding = 'utf-8')
        for line in f2:
            word2 = (line)
            if a1 == word2:

                continue
            else:
                a2 = a1
   ffinal = open("good.txt",mode = 'a',encoding = 'utf-8')
   ffinal.write(a2 + "\n")


**Below is a more complete description of the function:**
```

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

stemmer = Stemmer()
f1 = open("first.txt",mode = 'r',encoding = 'utf-8')
for line in f1:
    word1 = (line)
    word = str(word1)
    word = stemmer.stem(word)

    # Clear out empty lines
    if word[-1] == "\n":
        new_word = word.replace('\n', '')
    else:
        new_word = word
    #Now you need to clear the garbage (for now, all but words)
    if new_word.isalpha():
        a1 = new_word
    else:
        continue
    # Now you need to clear all Russian words
    f2 = open("base.txt",mode = 'r',encoding = 'utf-8')
    # inside the file all Russian words

    #here you need to write code that  
    #runs the variable a1 through the entire database



    #here is the code output
    ffinal = open("good.txt",mode = 'a',encoding = 'utf-8')
    ffinal.write(a1 + "\n")
```

Comment: what to do with it :?

Comment: I need the program to check a1 throughout the database, but my code is not working

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: This is not homework. I want to remove from one database all the words that are in another, the full functionality of the program is voluminous, it uses snowballstemmer

Comment: @JasonV  I added a question, Thanks for the response